# Form_for hepler:reduce default html class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have little form_for @user, which is password reset, and I don't want it to look like other @user edit forms.
But anything I tried didn't assign this form to something other than default html class of form_for, which is "edit_user".

Tried:

```
<%= form_for @user, :url=>update_pass_path(:class=>'reset_pass'), :method=>'put' do |f| %>
```

And:

```
 <%= form_for @user, :url=>update_pass_path, :class=>'reset_pass', :method=>'put' do |f| %>
```

Still edit_user.
Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass any html options as part of `options` hash

like this:

```
form_for(@user, :url=>update_pass_path, :html => { :class => "reset_pass", :method=>'put' }) do |f|
  .....
end
```

see the documentation: [Form for - API Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => update_pass_path, :html => { :class => "reset_pass" }, :method => 'put' do |f| %>
```